# Dynamically set animation in Angular ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation, angular-ui-router

I'm setting up an Angular app using ui router that needs to dynamically change the animation direction based on an argument, so it can animate `forward` and `backward`. I've based the animation off of this demo, and it's working great, but I can't figure out how to change the animation based on a parameter I pass to `state.go`.

http://plnkr.co/edit/GoKZJhGA3P14XNbzB9v9?p=preview

Comment: Animation in angular is CSS based. So you can pass a class name as parameter, and add it to `<div class="well" ui-view></div>`. But this is a dirty hack :(

Comment: @VladimirFurso Can you provide an updated Plunker with how to accomplish that?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/slemwr5glBp9hBBsPU5j?p=preview I've only changed leave animation. Sorry, i'm terrible at css.

Comment: another(not mine) example http://codepen.io/ShMcK/pen/kHxKy/